# Using XSD file in VS2005

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, xml-serialization

I want to write an XML file.  I have created an XSD file named XMLSchema.xsd, and run the command 'xsd /c XMLSchema.xsd' which generated a c# class file.  Now, how do I use this file to generate XML files?

Part of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" >
<xs:element name="root">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="Audit">
            <xs:complexType>
               ...
```

which generates a c# class 'root'.

How do I call 'root' from my C# web program?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `root.cs` file in your project, then it will be accessible.

In order to read and write XML files using this class, you need to use [serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As Oded said, you simply include the generated file in your project. As for loading/saving, you simply create a new XmlSerializer for your generated class, i.e. root. In code:

Loading:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(xmlFilePath))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        Root data;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

        try
        {
            data = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as T;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            // XML is invalid
            return null;
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Saving:

```
using (var fs = File.Create(targetPath))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```